# Filter rows on multiple columns in data Factory

Tags: azure, filter, dataset, azure-data-factory

I've recently started working on Microsoft Azure and more precisely Data Factory.
I want to clean my datasets before working on it in Azure ML so I've created some few steps with Data flow to do this. However, I have no idea how to work with multiple columns let me explain.

Let's say I have a dataset with 15 features (columns) and I want to filter outliers for each features and let's say I have like 500k rows. In other words, in my first column there are maybe 15 values that are outliers, in my second columns maybe 5 in my third let's say 10 etc... but these values are on different rows from each other.

What I want to do is filter out all values that are above or below a threshold and I want to do this for all columns not 1 column at a time. Because right now I can do this but I have to create a filter bloc for every column so here it will be 20 filter blocs.
I'm pretty sure that there is a way to do this but I just can't find it how.

I would really appreciate any help and if you have any question or things that aren't clear let me know I will be here to answer.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you using data flow? Are the filter conditions the same for all columns?

Comment: Hello, yes I am using data flow the condition will be the same for all columns yes it is a greater or lower than condition

Comment: Hi @Money Sneakers, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update:**

If of the columns is not satisfied, will an entire row be deleted.
I think we can take an easier way.
Using expression in the Filter activity:
`column1>30 && column1<100 && column2>35 && column2<95 && column3>40 && column3<90`

[image]

---

I came up with a relatively convenient method,we need use two Lookup activities and two Filter activities to filter multiple columns.
Here I will filter 3 columns, which the numbers in columns are greater than 30 less than 100.

1. Here is the data preview in the source,
   [image]
2. At `minValueSource`, I stored a min value in a csv in Azure datalake gen2. `maxValueSource` is the same as the `minValueSource`.
   [image]
3. Then I set up Lookup1 activity. In your case, you need to set up 25 columns here.
   [image]
4. Then we need to set up the `Optmize` tab at Lookup1 activity.
   [image]
5. The data preview looks like this, there will be `null` if one of the columns contains a value less than 30.
   [image]
6. At Filter1 activity, we can use expression `!isNull(minValue)` to filter the values less than 30.
   [image]
7. It is the same setting at Lookup2 and Filter2 activity. I will not show here.
   [image]
8. At sink, we can set the mapping tab to choose the columns which we need.
   [image]

I think it is easier than set 20 or more filter blocs.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer and explanation I think that is what I've been looking to do. However, when I try to do what you did I get some little errors that I don't really understand.
First, I created a min value csv only containing one value and one column like you but when I import it in my dataflow it creates 2 column, the first one column_1 and the second one is the min_value. Then, when I do the lookup I can only select the column_1 which is empty so will return Null all the time.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I fixed it. When I created my dataset min value I chose blob storage and not datalake gen2

Comment: Nice, you solved the error.If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is useful one last thing, I want to filter multiple columns but each columns will be filtered given a unique value
So column 1 is filtered if value is < min_value_1 etc... 
Should I make a csv with X coolumns where X is the number of column I have in my original dataset and each column has its own value of filtering?

Comment: If of the columns is not satisfied, will an entire row be deleted?

Comment: Oh god I've been trying to find something like this since I started working couple weeks ago. I saw nothing about it so I did not even try yoou know even though I worked with Javascript before. 
Thanks a lot man